# Mapstruct generating random mapper implementation class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

Now, Let's assume I'm working in a branch 'feature' of my project, and I write a MapStruct mapper interface and build/run it, but later on I find that I don't need this mapper, so I refactor and delete this file.
Now, after I refactored and deleted this mapper interface, I tried running the application but am unable to do so, as it throws FileNotFoundException.

Also, when I undeleted the mapper interface, I am able to run the application.

PS:
Language - Java-11
Framework - SpringBoot (Gradle)
IDE - IntelliJ IDEA(CE)

Can someone please help me find out the reason I'm still getting this error?

Comment: Your question is too vague. I could be anything. In general if your code compiles well after you deleted the class `MapStruct` it should run as well. Make sure that `MapStruct` is not used by any other client code or is e.g. referenced in a xml Spring context file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.